# What is the complexity of finding permutation this way?

Tags: java, algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

This method :

```
private static void permutation(String prefix, String str)
{
  int n = str.length();
  if(n==0)
    System.out.println(prefix);
  else
  {
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
      permutation(prefix+str.charAt(i),str.substring(0,i)+str.substring(i+1,n));
  }
}
```

finds all the permutations of a String. when invoked with `permutation("","ABC");`
it prints:

```
ABC
ACB
BAC
BCA
CAB
CBA
```

Now, the question is : what is the complexity of this method? Is it `O(n!)` or `O(nlogn)`. An answer with recurrence tree would be very helpful! Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Neither :-)

Let T(n,k) be the number of step taken for an invocation of permutation where k is the length of `str`.

Obviously, T(n, 0) = O(n).

For 1 < k <= n, we have k executions of the loop body, each of which does some string concatentation (which costs O(n)) and a recursive invocation costing T(n, k-1). Therefore,

```
T(n,k) = k (O(n) + T(n,k-1)).
```

An easy way to guess the closed form of this recurrence is writing out a few terms:

```
T(n,k) = k * (n + (k-1) * (n + T(n,k-2)))
```

lets separate all these n terms:

```
       = kn + k(k-1)n + k(k-1)T(n,k-2)
```

and expand a little more

```
       = kn + k(k-1)n + k(k-1)(k-2)n + k(k-1)(k-2)T(n,k-3)
```

this suggests that

```
T(n,k) = kn + k(k-1)n + k(k-1)(k-2)n + ... + k!n
       = n (k + k(k-1) + k(k-1)(k-2) + ... + k!)
```

and

```
T(n,n) = n (n + n(n-1) + n(n-1)(n-2) + ... + n!)
       = nn! (1/(n-1)! + 1/(n-2)! + 1/(n-3)! + ... + 1)
             \-----------------   --------------------/
                               \ /
                            1 < x < 2
```

therefore T(n,n) = O(nn!)

Comment: I think the correct bounds on the bracketed term is 1 <= x < e, not 1 < x < 2. But more seriously, the string concatenations are, I think, O(n^2) and not O(n), since each is O(n), but there's a loop of size n.

Comment: There is a loop of size k, not n. And the recurrence relation accounts for that, because k(n + ...) = kn + k...

Comment: As for the bound: While it is certainly correct that x < e, we can easily give a tighter bound by observing that,1/(n!) <= 1/2^n, and the sum of that geometric series is 2.

Comment: you're quite right. sum(1/n!) = e (which is why I thought the bound was e), but that's if you sum from 0 to infinity. Your sum starts at 1 (not 0) so bounded by e-1, but 2 is a much easier to understand bound.

Comment: I upvoted you. I'm not sure why the other answer is upvoted and accepted given that it's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

## First Attempt

Since you are **printing** *each* permutation of an `n`-string and there are such `n!` strings, the time complexity *appears* `O(n!)`.

The recurrence can be shown pictorially (not complete, but you should get the idea) as follows:

```
             -------------- p("", "ABC")------------
            /                 |                 \
      p("A", "BC")        p("B", "AC")        p("C", "AB")
       |         |  
p("AB", "C")    p("AC", "B")
       |             |
p("ABC", "")     p("ACB", "")
```

As you can see, the leaves of the call tree have the required permutation in the form of `prefix` which you print in the base case. Since the number of leaves in this tree is `n!`, the complexity *appears* `O(n!)`.

An intuitive reasoning why it is not (as low as) `O(nlogn)` is that other recurrences that are `O(nlogn)` do not look like this. For instance, in case of merge sort, you halve the problem size and do a linear merge operation in each step. Since there are `log(n)` steps, you get `O(nlog(n))` as the solution of the recurrence. In this problem however, since you have got to do much, much more work, the time complexity is higher.

## Updates After Comments

The analysis in the first attempt above is not quite right. There's much more going on here. It's true that the call tree has `n!` leaves. But in order to get to those leaves we have got to do much more work at every non-leaf node representing a recursive call. The number of nodes in the first level is clearly `n` for a string `str` that has `n` characters. There are also string concatenations going on before the next recursive call is made. These make it even more time consuming. Each of the `n` calls end up appending a total of at least `n` characters.

At the second level, each of those `n` nodes give rise to `(n-1)` nodes, giving a total of `n(n-1)`. Again, there are as many string concatenations.

This process continues till the recursion bottoms out giving `n!` leaves in the call tree. The total number of nodes in the call tree is

```
= n + n(n-1) + n(n-1)(n-2) + ... + n(n-1)(n-2)...1
= n(n-1)(n-2)...1 + n(n-1)(n-2)...2 + n(n-1)(n-2)...3 + ... + n(n-1) + n
= n! + (n!/2) + (n!/(2.3)) + ... + (n!/(1.2.3...(n-1)) --- these are n terms
= n! (1 + 1/2 + 1/2.3 + 1/2.3.4 + ...)
= n! (1.71828...)
= O(n!)
```

In each of these calls, there are at least `n` characters being appended (and as Paul points out, one new line is being printed), the total amount of work is `O(n.n!)`.

Comment: There's (n+1)! characters output, and (n+1)! isn't O(n!) so this answer can't be right.

Comment: @PaulHankin I think they are not `(n+1)!`, but `n.n!` (18 = 3.3!) characters output if `n = length("str")`. But I agree,  the number of calls to `permutation` is more than `O(n!)`.

Comment: Each line has (n+1) characters: n digits and a carriage return. So (n+1)! total.